# How to pass multiple parameter in URL Ajax request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

I'm trying to pass two parameters in a url via an ajax request, like as follows:

```
  function request(time, clientId) {
  return $.ajax({
  url: 'https://myURL/api/v1/get-infoDevices?value=Logs&duration=86400000&time='+time+'&ID='+clientId,
  type: 'get',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json'
  });
  }
```

and the request call looks like this:

```
request((input.dashboard.time, input.ctx.clientId).done((res) =>{
   code hear
}
```

when I just pass the team, the request works perfectly. But when I add the `clientID`, it gives an error in the call.

How do I call two or more arguments implementing in the url and calling in the request?

Comment: Please post the error details and the values of both variables while calling the function

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code other than the fact that you have syntax errors when you're calling the function. It should be `request(param1, param2).done((res) => { //do stuff here })`